# How to pull out the values of ticked checkboxes using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ $id=$row[id];
  $html=<<<html
<tr><td> 
<input style="float:left" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"  value="$id">   
<span style="float:left">$row[content]</span>
<span style="color:black;float:right">$row[submitter]</span></td></tr>  
html;
echo $html; 
}
```

Since the HTML code is generated dynamically, I don't know how long the array "mycheckbox" is and I don't know what checkboxes are ticked or unticked(This is determined by users).  How to retrieve the values of ticked checkboxes using PHP?

Comment: To be perfectly honest with you, this is a real programming question so I'd delete it and create a non-CW version. You are, in my experience, more likely to get help that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now, mycheckbox will get overwritten and act more like a radio button.

You probably want:

```
<input style="float:left" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[]"  value="$id">
```

PHP will push the checked values into an array: $_GET['mycheckbox']

```
<?php 

$values = $_GET['mycheckbox'];
$count = count($values);

echo 'Selected values are: <br/>';

foreach($values as $val) {
    echo $val . '<br/>';
}

echo 'Total Length is: ' . $count . '<br/>';
```